# Grabbing that all important data from mySQL from jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following jQuery statement:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db.php",
        data: "word="+ tmpWord,
        success: function(){
            //somehow get the word here ^_^
        }
    });
```

This is an excerpt from db.php:

```
$word = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['word']));
$addClient  = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = " . $word;
mysql_query($addClient) or die(mysql_error());
```

My question to you good people is: How can I retrieve `$word` from `db.php`?

[ *scratches head* ]

---

**[edit] Ok, so that was solved - Thanks sarfraz.**

---

I'm now getting an error showing, here it is:
`Unknown column 'apple' in 'where clause'`

The query I am using looks like this:
`$addClient = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'apple'`

And my sql is like this:

```
dictionary
|_ wID, word, definition, email, url, placeholder1, placeholder2

    0  apple  null        null   null     null        null
```

PHP MyAdmin states:

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)
SQL query: SELECT *
FROM dictionary
WHERE word = 'apple'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When using: `SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = 'apple'`

---

**FINAL EDIT**
THIS HAS BEEN SOLVED!

For some unknown reason I had to change trigger_error() to die().

Cheers.

Comment: Why do you want to retrieve the same word?

Comment: ah, it was just a bad example - just wanted to connect for now and retrieve the row

Comment: `$addClient = "SELECT...` is not a query. It's PHP code ad you cannot see it in the form you posted here. So, you posted faked code, a VERY BAD thing. Print out actual query and see it's real contents

Comment: wait, maybe i didnt understand - that is a mysql query isn't it?

Comment: no need to understand. just print it out, to ensure you're sending proper query to mysql

Comment: Anyway, your problem is not of the kind to be solved on the external site. But of the kind to be solved by your own efforts. Make a simpler example, get rid of AJAX for a while, print as much info as possible. Double check everything (if you save proper file, connect to the proper database, etc). DEBUG it.

Comment: deary me, I can't be any more plain - my database is populated correctly, my php connect and retrieves a result - my AJAX calls that php. but when the AJAX gets the result - its and empty string, EVEN though the sql query says it returned 1 row.

Comment: congratulations, that you have solved it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how your jQuery code should look like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "db.php",
        data: "word="+ tmpWord,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
});
```

And PHP Code:

```
$word = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['word']));
$query = "SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word = '$word'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
// send back the word to ajax request
echo $row['word'];
```

Comment: Hey that works nicely (+1) but I'm getting an error in mySQL now :( - I'm amending my answer.

Comment: Can you paste in what the query is which gives you the error?

Comment: I now get this response: `(an empty string)`

Comment: Make sure that your query returns data, you can run your query in mysql client to check.

Comment: @Neurofluxation: Your query shows that no records were found so empty response.

Comment: but my database has data in it... it has the word `apple` in it... I'm really confused.